# How to display data recieved from remote server via Twitter typeahed.js

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I need to change DropDown to autocomplete and  I'm using [Twitter typeahed.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) for this.
And my problem is I **can't display** data in autocomplete field that I'm recieved from server.

It's my **clients code** with request:

```
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            remote: 'Home/MeteringSystemList?q=%QUERY',
            templates: {
                empty: [
                  '<div class="empty-message">',
                  'no results',
                  '</div>'
                ].join('\n')
            },
            source: function(query, process) {
                return $.get('/Home/MeteringSystemList', { query: query }, function(data) {
                    //var arr = $.map(data, function(result) { return result; });
                    var resultList = $.map(JSON.parse(data), function(item) {
                        var aItem = {
                            id: item.MeteringSystem_EntityInstanceID,
                            name: item.City + ", " + item.Address + ", " + item.MeteringType_ShortName
                                + " (" + item.FactoryNumber + ", " + item.HeatMeter_ModelName + ")"
                        };
                        return JSON.stringify(aItem);
                    });
                    console.log(resultList);
                    return process(resultList);

                });
            }
        });
```

And it's my **server-side code** which finding and filtering data:

```
public JsonResult MeteringSystemList(string query)
    {
        //var list = new List<string[]>();
        string output = "";
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if(query != null)
        {
            using (var context = new MCSysContainer())
            {

            query = query.ToLowerInvariant();

                var result = from db in context.GetMeteringSystemsList(userId)
                    where db.Address.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query) ||
                          db.City.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query) ||
                          db.FactoryNumber.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query) ||
                          db.HeatMeter_ModelName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query)
                    select db;
                output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
            }
        }

        return Json(output , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In Chrome console I see my data like JSON-object but I can't get them out to display.

```
["{"id":53212,"name":"Минск, Курчатова, д.7, null (102911, TЭM-104-1)"}", "{"id":53214,"name":"Минск, Курчатова, д.7, null (1660, TЭM-05М)"}", "{"id":53267,"name":"Минск, Курчатова, д.7, null (1547730, TЭM-104-4)"}", "{"id":53268,"name":"Минск, Курчатова, д.7, null (1547730, TЭM-104-4)"}"]
```

I will appreciate any help which can help to solve my problem.
thanks everybody for your attention and your time.

**UPDATE**
I'm modified my client's code. Added Bloodhound engine and it's starts working

```
var urldata = '@Url.Action("MeteringSystemList", "Home")' + '?query=%QUERY';


    var jsondataresult = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

        remote: {
            url: urldata,
            wildcard: '%QUERY',
            filter: function (response) {

                console.log(response);
                return $.map(JSON.parse(response), function (object) {

                    return {
                        id: object.MeteringSystem_EntityInstanceID,
                        name: object.City + ", " + object.Address + ", " + object.MeteringType_ShortName
                            + " (" + object.FactoryNumber + ", " + object.HeatMeter_ModelName + ")"
                    };

                });
            }
        }
    });

    $('#autocomplite').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="empty-message">',
                'поиск не дал результатов',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n')
        },
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: jsondataresult 
    }).on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", function (e, data) {
        $("#meteringId").val(data.id);

    });
    $('.typeahead.input-sm').siblings('input.tt-hint').addClass('hint-small');
    $('.typeahead.input-lg').siblings('input.tt-hint').addClass('hint-large');
```

It's work fine excepting one thing. It's suggesting just **one first** item from list.